# How can I compare two arrays to fill a third?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, merge

Imagine I have an array containing the following values:

```
$indexes = [ 'Hello' , 'Hoi', 'Ola' , 'Shalom' , 'Salaam'];
```

Furthermore I also have  an incomplete array:

```
$values = ['Hello' => 2, 'Ola' => 20 ];
```

How can I merge these arrays to get a result displaying all indexes with their values, and 0 when no value is found?

```
$desiredResult = [
 'Hello' => 2, 
 'Hoi' => 0, 
 'Ola' => 20 ,
 'Shalom' => 0,
 'Salaam' => 0
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$indexes = [ 'Hello' , 'Hoi', 'Ola' , 'Shalom' , 'Salaam'];
$values = ['Hello' => 2, 'Ola' => 20 ];

$default = array_combine($indexes, array_fill(0, count($indexes), 0));

$result = array_replace($default, $values);

var_dump($result);
```

The result would be:

```
array(5) {
  ["Hello"]=>
  int(2)
  ["Hoi"]=>
  int(0)
  ["Ola"]=>
  int(20)
  ["Shalom"]=>
  int(0)
  ["Salaam"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use built-in functions (see other answers), but you can of course also loop yourself.

```
function addKeys(&$arr, $keys, $value = 0) {
  foreach ($keys as $key) {
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
      $arr[$key] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $arr;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/Idok/0)

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_merge and array_combine, [live demo](https://eval.in/814458).

```
$disiredResult = array_merge(
   array_combine($indexes, array_fill(0, count($indexes), 0)), $values
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is `array_combine` which works like 
`array_combine($indexes, $values)`